# Просмотр состояния регистров

Tags: ассемблер

Имеется программа на ассемблере написанная в среде MS VS с помощью оператора _asm. Необходимо просмотреть состояние регистров которые используются и значения которые в них находятся в разные промежутки времени.
Например
AEX 15d
ECX 48d
AH 2d
Подскажите как это можно сделать стандартным отладчиком или доп. софтом.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Имеется в виду ассемблерная вставка в С или С++ код? Тогда смотрите состояние регистров встроенным отладчиком в MS VS, благо он умеет это делать.